# I dont have the denoise option

Tags: rendering

once again it seems i dont have an option blender guru does but i dont think its my fault this time- i think. he says we have to click the denoise option under sampling but my menu is different to his. its probably right in front of my eyes but i dont understand stuff

[image: blender gurus pic]
[image: my pic]

Comment: are you in Eevee or Cycles?

Comment: you need Cycles to do this. Change render engine to cycles.

Comment: yes i am in cycles

Answer (score 2):

### Are you using the same version of Blender as your tutorial?

Later versions of Blender moved the denoising options around. I recommend using the latest complete Blender release.

If you're following an older Blender Guru tutorial, some options might be in slightly different places.

These controls (before Blender 3.x):

[image: denoise]

Do the same thing as these (after 3.x):

[image: denoise2]